# How to install Nvidia drivers and run unity 3d?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I am having a hard time installing the Nvidia drivers on my Dell XPS l502x. 
Specs: Intel core i5 (2nd gen)
       8GB RAM
       Nvidia GeForce GT 525M/ also has integrated Intel graphics as well
       Running Ubuntu 12.04 lts

When I install nvidia-current from software center and try to go to the nvidia settings,i get the following message: `You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run`nvidia-xconfig`as root), and restart the X server`

How can I fix this because I want to try running unity 3d. I did a lot of searching and tried all of the suggestions out there but nothing worked. I know my graphics card is supported in the nvidia-current driver from the software center because it is listed in the   /usr/share/doc/nvidia-current/README.txt.gz. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the nvidia driver you need to re-start X. Log out and back in.